# How to implement usage of refresh token with next-auth

Tags: axios, access-token, interceptor, next-auth, refresh-token

I'm currently working with a backend that uses Django, DRF, and simple_jwt for authorization. On the frontend, I have React, Next.js, and next-auth. I've successfully implemented the retrieval of the access token from the session using useSession() and getServerSession().

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to use the refresh token in Next.js. Does anyone have suggestions or best practices for this?

I've come across an example that uses Axios interceptors. In the interceptor, I need to get both the refresh and access tokens. However, there are two methods to achieve this: one for the client-side (useSession()) and another for the server-side (getServerSession()). How can I combine these two methods within a single interceptor? Or should I set up two separate interceptors?